# Get node count for each value of a CCK Options Widgets field

Tags: views, entities

Lets say I have a CCK options widget field with 4 options like
1
2
3
4

If I want to get the node count for these values how could I do that?

Also, how would I do it if I would like to put this result in a View and sort on it? Use a computed field?

Comment: What do you mean by "node count for these values" can you provide us a better example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Views Group By](http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby) is just what you need. It enriches D6 & Views2 functionality with SQL Grouping and Aggregation capabilities. Once installed, configure it roughly along these lines:

**Fields to Group On:** Your Field
**SQL Aggregation Function:** Count
**Fields to Aggregate with the SQL Function:** Node NID
**Fields to Sort Resultset On (after SQL Function is Applied):** Your Field
**Sort Direction:** Descending

Please, note, this will only select those fields that have non-zero number of nodes that they are selected for. To work around that, depending on your scenario you might be able to use a taxonomy vocabulary to replace your options widget and then build a Term View type based on that vocabulary.